# JQuery Mobile 1.4 Won't Display <label>s for Dynamically Added Input Controls

Tags: jquery-mobile

After upgrading from JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 to 1.4.2, the labels associated with dynamically added input fields (text and select boxes) are no longer being displayed. Before, the application looked like this:

[image]

The address fields are supposed to change to reflect an address format appropriate for the selected country, in this case, Denmark.

After the upgrade, I now get this result when I select a country:

[image]

In Firebug the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="meeting_address" class="ui-field-contain">
<fieldset class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all" data-role="controlgroup">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <label class="addr_name" for="name-meetingAddress">Location Name</label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input id="name-meetingAddress" class="field_meeting_address" type="text" value="" maxsize="40" size="40" name="name-meetingAddress">
        </div>
        <label class="addr_street_address" for="street1-meetingAddress">Street Address</label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input id="street1-meetingAddress" class="field_meeting_address" type="text" value="" maxsize="40" size="40" name="street1-meetingAddress">
        </div>
        <label class="addr_street_address2" for="street2-meetingAddress"></label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input id="street2-meetingAddress" class="field_meeting_address" type="text" value="" maxsize="40" size="40" name="street2-meetingAddress">
        </div>
        <label class="dk_addr_village" for="urbanization-meetingAddress">Village</label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input id="urbanization-meetingAddress" class="field_meeting_address" type="text" value="" maxsize="40" size="40" name="urbanization-meetingAddress">
        </div>
        <label class="addr_postcode" for="postcode-meetingAddress">Post Code</label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input id="postcode-meetingAddress" class="field_meeting_address" type="text" value="" maxsize="4" size="4" name="postcode-meetingAddress">
        </div>
        <label class="addr_district" for="district-meetingAddress">District</label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input id="district-meetingAddress" class="field_meeting_address" type="text" value="" maxsize="20" size="20" name="district-meetingAddress">
        </div>
        <label class="addr_city" for="city-meetingAddress">City</label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input id="city-meetingAddress" class="field_meeting_address" type="text" value="" maxsize="40" size="40" name="city-meetingAddress">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The only change I made after upgrading was changing `<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="meeting_address">` to `<div id="meeting_address" class="ui-field-contain">`. I tried calling `.enhanceWithin()` on various items with no effect. I didn't need to do anything to initialize these controls in JQM 1.3.1. What changed in how JQM 1.4 handles this situation, and what do I need to do to get back the previous behavior?

Comment: how do you add them dynamically? pls share your js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the label issue, you need to wrap each `label` and its' associate `input` in a div with class `ui-field-contain` <sup>(1)</sup>.

In jQuery Mobile 1.4, if *controlgroup* is existing, elements should be appended to `$(".selector").controlgroup("container")` not to `$(".selector")` directly.

After you append all elements, you need to enhance those elements `.enhanceWithin()` and re-enhance (refresh) *controlgroup* not the container `.controlgroup("refresh")`.

```
var input = '<div class="ui-field-contain">' +
              '<label for="username">Username</label>' +
              '<input type="text" id="username" />' +
            '</div>';

$("#controlgroupID")
    .controlgroup("container")
    .append(input);

$("#controlgroupID")
    .enhanceWithin()
    .controlgroup("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UhhB7/)**

---

<sup>(1)</sup> `data-role="fieldcontain"` is deprecated and will be removed on jQM 1.5. The replacement is div with class `ui-field-contain`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the excellent post and the demo. I accept your answer!